# Compilation errors when trying to include a header only library (tiny-dnn) in VS2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, tiny-dnn

Apologies for the images of text. I don't have access to the originals.

I am running VS2015 on MS10. I am trying to implement the sample code from the docs: https://tiny-dnn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/Getting-started.html

The following code does not compile:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <iostream>
#include "tiny_dnn/tiny_dnn.h"

using namespace tiny_dnn;
using namespace tiny_dnn::activation;
using namespace tiny_dnn::layers;

int main(){
    network<sequential> net;
    net << fully_connected_layer(2, 3) << sigmoid_layer()
        << fully_connected_layer(3, 1) << sigmoid_layer();
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following errors:

[image]

I added the root folder to my includes:

[image]
[image]

It looks like many identifiers are missing:

[image]

Also, I had the following compilation error until I forced it to go away with the define. Might be related:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 0) you are posting images of text 1) you are mixing compilation errors and intellisense errors 2) this library does not seem to support VS

Comment: Apologies for the images of text. I don't have access to the originals.

Comment: It is listed on their GitHub that the requirements are gcc 4.9+, clang 3.6+ or VS 2015+

Comment: You may want to create a new issue then. If library claims to be compatible with VS then using it should not require performing excessive warning suppression. Also windows build has failed status...

Comment: I have already done that, but then I assumed the problem was on my part & was something general, that is why I posted a question here.

Answer (score 0):

I know it might be too late after 3 years ,but i hop it would be useful ,  it seems that your code has an issue related to [_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/scl-secure-no-warnings?view=msvc-160) which might be caused by Calling any of the potentially unsafe methods in the C++ Standard Library that results in Compiler Warning (level 3) , that is probably caused by something used in tiny-dnn library. To disable this warning, define the directive  `_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` in your code before any header include or If you use precompiled headers, put this directive in your precompiled header file before other includes.

```
#define _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include "tiny_dnn/tiny_dnn.h"

using namespace tiny_dnn;
using namespace tiny_dnn::activation;
using namespace tiny_dnn::layers;

int main(){
    network<sequential> net;
    net << fully_connected_layer(2, 3) << sigmoid_layer()
        << fully_connected_layer(3, 1) << sigmoid_layer();
    return 0;
}
```

another thing to notice tiny-dnn is designed with the -std=c++14 standard if your using tiny-dnn with newer standard like -std=c++17 you might also get some warnings that might be threated as errors considering your compiler options then you have to define the corresponding directive, for instance  `#define _SILENCE_ALL_CXX17_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS` for c++17